# Read List from Tapestry in jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json, tapestry

I have a List of favorites for users and I get that list in Index.java page:

```
List<Favorite> favorites = userService
                .getFavoritesByUserId(userSession.getUsrId());
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();      
for (Favorite f : favorites) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject().put("desc", getDescription());
      jsonArray.put(jsonObject);                
}
javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("favs", jsonArray);
```

and I want to get this array since a *.js file.
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$.extend(Tapestry.Initializer, {
     favorites:function(favs){
       console.log(favs)
}
})
```

Is there any solution? or an alternative better solution no using JSONArray?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function favs

`javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("favs", jsonArray);`

But the function is called favorites

`favorites:function(favs){`